# Taking KDE config files with me

Tags: configuration, kde, kde4, kde-apps

I'm reinstalling my Kubuntu 12.04 and I want to take my `Kate, Kile, Okular, Dolphin & Konsole` config files with me.

Where are this files located? I've looked around `/home/`, `/home/.kde/` and `/home/.config/` but found nothing.

Comment: Close voters. This question is about a more current release and has a IMHO higher quality answer. (requested merge)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got an answer in the [Kubuntu Forums](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59589-Taking-KDE-config-files-with-me) by **oshunluvr**. Here it is:

I believe they're all in `/home/USERNAME/.kde/share/config` and `/home/USERNAME/.kde/share/apps`.

Most of the configs are named `PROGRAMrc`, like `katerc` for kate and so on. The `../apps` directory contains add-ons like skins and plugins.

Comment: I just had trouble with Kate hanging on exit and finally fixed it by removing ~/.local/share/kate/, so for Kate, here is the full list of config files as far as I know:
~/.kde/share/config/kate*
~/.kde/share/apps/kate*
~/.config/kate*
~/.local/share/kate*

Answer (score 7):

**KDE releases**

In the past the KDE was released under the single label (KDE3, KDE4). Now the KDE is releasing as separate items the KDE Frameworks 5 (KF5). Plasma 5 and the KDE Applications. KDE Schedules [here](https://community.kde.org/Schedules).

**KDE4**

The KDE4 based applications are using environment variables - KDEHOME:

KDE System Administration/Environment Variables information [here](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Environment_Variables) and [here](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Environment_Variables#KDEHOME).

If not set, KDE uses `~/.kde` as directory where your personal data is stored.

Dolphin, KDE file manager, build with the KDE4 libraries. Configuration files are saved to the `$KDEHOME/share/config/` ,if set, otherwise to the `~/.kde/share/config/`

[image]

**KF5 (KDE Frameworks 5)**

The KF5 based applications are following the Freedesktop.org [standards and specifications](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/).

XDG Base Directory Specification [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

> $XDG_DATA_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user
>   specific data files should be stored. If $XDG_DATA_HOME is either not
>   set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.local/share should be used.
>
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user
>   specific configuration files should be stored. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is
>   either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.config should be
>   used.

Dolphin, KDE file manager, build with the KF5. Configuration files are saved to the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` ,if set, otherwise to the `~/.config`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They are supposed to be in your '/home/username/' they are hidden directories with a . in front of them.

I am just not sure whether they were just in '/home/username/.kate' or in '/home/username/.kde/applications/'

But I am 100% sure that they are in you '/home/username/' directory. You could just try to copy your entire home to your new system. That would also retain them.

Comment: To view all hidden files, do C-h. And also, some config files are hidden files, some are located within hidden folders, such as .mozilla and .thunderbird

Comment: @asymptotically I mentioned I had already checked some hidden folders, so I know how to see hidden folders and files; thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jochen there are no `/home/username/.kate` (or `../.kile`, etc..) or `/home/username/.kde/applications/` folders in my system. I don't want to copy the entire /home/ folder, I just want those particular files/folders. They have to be there somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to demean you or anything, just added to Jochen's answer for complete clarity :P

Comment: Config files are always stored in you home folder. You could try a: `find /home/username/ -name '*kate*'` and see which folders it finds. This will also work for other programs just change the search part of the command.

Comment: @asymptotically No offense taken mate. Cheers.