# Where does Okular store its config files?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, kde, pdf

I'm trying to pre-configure `Okular` to add it to my custom Ubuntu image. but I can't seem to find the right config files. I need to edit the main toolbar to add a few more buttons like a fullscreen button that is easy to access with one click. the files in the ~/.config folder(okularrc and okularpartrc) don't seem to store the toolbar settings and can't find the ones that do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking KDE config files with me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167955/taking-kde-config-files-with-me)

Comment: @MarkJ.Adams already read that question, I'm using Lubuntu image as my base and I don't have .kde folder. actually even copying everything in the Home directory doesn't work

Comment: Filed a bug at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416729

Answer (score 8):

As you've found, neither `~/.config/okularpartrc` nor `~/.config/okularrc` store information relating to changes made to the main toolbar.

Here's an image of the toolbar I have before adding a couple of buttons:

[image: before]

I then used the GUI found in `Settings` > `Configure Toolbars` to add a couple of buttons (outlined in red) as seen below:

[image: after]

I found that these changes were recorded in `~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/okular/shell.rc`,  in **Kubuntu 18.04**.

On running `diff` on `shell.rc` before and after the changes I get:

```
$ diff 0shell.rc 1shell.rc
24a25
>   <Separator weakSeparator="1"/>
58a60,61
>   <Action name="help_contents"/>
>   <Action name="help_about_kde"/>
$
```

Of course, the line numbers maybe different on your system.

*You've mentioned that copying the entire home folder doesn't help and I would assume that `~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/okular/shell.rc` would be copied as well in which case you should have been able to carry over the changes. It's possible that something else is required but I don't know what that would be.*

**Edit**: I just installed `okular` on Lubuntu 18.04. The same file, `~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/okular/shell.rc`, exists there as well.

Comment: It's weird, on Ubuntu 20.04, with a snap installation of Okular, none of the files `/snap/okular/98/usr/share/kxmlgui5/okular/{part.rc, part-viewermode.rc, shell.rc}` are modified when I change the toolbar settings in the GUI...

Comment: ah! found it! it's in my home directory path: `~/snap/okular/98/.local/share/kxmlgui5/okular/part.rc`.
I guess if I modified the "okular_shell" options in the GUI, I would see the file  `~/snap/okular/98/.local/share/kxmlgui5/okular/shell.rc` appear as well.

Comment: If ever someone landed here looking for the config files location on *windows*, they reside in ```AppData\Local\okular\``` under your home (profile) directory (generally ```C:\Users\your_login```).

Answer (score 3):

By defining some marker pens and applying `sudo find . -atime -1 -type f > ~/q` and searching in the result file `/q` for all occurrences of "okular" I finally found this file for a snap-installed Okular Version 1.7.2 on Xubuntu 18.04, which had the proper atime-stamp:

```
~/snap/okular/63/.config/okularpartrc
```

It is a printable file. All annotation marker pen definitions follow the heading

```
[Reviews]
AnnotationTools=
```

and follow e.g. this pattern

```
<tool name="rot 25" id="5" type="highlight"><engine color="#ffff0000" type="TextSelector"><annotation color="#ffff0000" type="Highlight" opacity="0.25"/></engine><shortcut>5</shortcut></tool>
```